# hashCode and equals implementation not working

Tags: apex, hashcode

I am not getting a match when using the `containsKey` method on a `Map` of this custom object type:

**Custom Apex Type**

```
public class StateTransition
{
    final ProcessState CurrentState;
    final Command Command;

    public StateTransition(ProcessState currentState, Command command)
    {
        CurrentState = currentState;
        Command = command;
    }

    public Integer hashCode()
    {
        return 17 + 31 * CurrentState.hashCode() + 31 * Command.hashCode();
    }

    public Boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        StateTransition other = (StateTransition) obj;
        return other != null && this.CurrentState == other.CurrentState && this.Command == other.Command;
    }
}
```

Both `ProcessState` and `Command` are `Enum` types.

What is wrong with the implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is the naming conflict in your constructor. When you use the pattern you have, your code simply reassigns the constructor parameter, rather than the object attribute. If they have the same name, you need to use `this.` to reference the attribute instead of the constructor parameter.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Foo param1;
    public Bar param2;
    public MyClass(Foo param1, Bar param2)
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
//      ^^^^^
        this.param2 = param2;
//      ^^^^^
    }
}
```

It is easy enough to verify your attributes are not being set via an anonymous script:

```
Enum ProcessState { FOO, BAR }
Enum Command { FOO, BAR }

class StateTransition
{
    final ProcessState CurrentState;
    final Command Command;
    StateTransition(ProcessState currentState, Command command)
    {
        CurrentState = currentState;
        Command = command;
    }
}

StateTransition demo = new StateTransition(ProcessState.FOO, Command.BAR);
system.assertEquals(null, demo.CurrentState);
system.assertEquals(null, demo.Command);
```

Comment: Do I even need the custom implementations of `hashCode` and `equals`?

Comment: @Robs for using it in containsKey, yes you do.

Comment: @Robs - If you use ApexMocks for unit testing, you also may need `hashCode` and `equals` as ApexMocks matchers need these helpers